# Retrieve a single entry from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is my firebase data.

```
users
    a81b0dec-671e-4840-9977-e932274928fb  
       email: "s@s.com"
       screenname: "SSS"
       totalmoney: "0"
       uid: "a81b0dec-671e-4840-9977-e932274928fb"
    c934beeb-51d2-4919-bff0-64153abff1dd
       email: "p@p.com"
       screenname: "PPP"
       totalmoney: "0"
       uid: "c934beeb-51d2-4919-bff0-64153abff1dd"
    e0187af9-20a9-4088-a86c-7fb8cf3b4d47
       email: "o@o.com"
       screenname: "OOO"
       totalmoney: "0"
       uid: "e0187af9-20a9-4088-a86c-7fb8cf3b4d47"
```

How can I retrieve the node with uid = "a81b0dec-671e-4840-9977-e932274928fb".
Here's what I have tried so far, but it's not working.

```
String uid = "a81b0dec-671e-4840-9977-e932274928fb";
Query query = fb.orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("SINGLE VALUE EVENT", data.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Comment: "it is not working" is incredibly vague. What did you expect the code to do? What did it do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code executes a query. Since a query can match multiple child nodes, it returns a list of values. Even when there is only one matching result, it returns a list of one.

You can handle this in your code by iterating through the children:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
  for (DataSnapshot userSnap: data.getChildren) {
    Log.i("SINGLE VALUE EVENT", userSnap.child("email").getValue(String.class));
  }
}
```

But in this case you don't even need a query, since you've (wisely) also stored the users under their uid. That means you can directly access the user by that uid, which saves some code and will be faster:

```
String uid = "a81b0dec-671e-4840-9977-e932274928fb";
DatabaseReference user = fb.child(uid);
user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot data) {
    Log.i("SINGLE VALUE EVENT", data.child("email").getValue(String.class));
  }
  public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
    Log.e(TAG, error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't duplicate the id, instead use:

```
ref.orderByKey().equalTo()
```

You can find what you are searching for there:

https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html

Answer (score 0):

**To make your code more dynamic..you could declare a string for getting the uid values**

```
     EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String edtText = edt.getText().toString().trim();
     String uid = edtText;

    DatabaseReference db  = fb.child(uid);
    db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email for supplied user is : " + snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
Toast.makeText(this,"Error as a result of " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that you're expecting only one entry (in this case since every record has a unique id), using psudo code I'd say, retrieve the 0 index of returned data.

Comment: If you give an example that will be better, I guess.